# Can't seem to run code in Stack Snippets?

Tags: support

I wanted to post a question in SO, but I can't seem to run the code in Stack Snippets. I assume that if it doesn't run there, someone's going to downvote. I guess that if I have a question on how to post a question in SO, then Meta would be the place for that question.

This is how my HTML file looks like, and the graph is generated correctly in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 chart Boilerplate Example</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
<script>
/* global d3, _ */

(function() {
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 50},
    margin2  = {top: 210, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width    = 764 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height   = 283 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2  = 283 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y').parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    legendFormat = d3.time.format('%b %d, %Y');

  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2  = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y   = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y1  = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2  = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]),
    y3  = d3.scale.linear().range([60, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
    xAxis2  = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient('bottom'),
    yAxis   = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');

  var priceLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

  var avgLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.average); });

  var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 60);

  svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
  .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var make_y_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left')
      .ticks(3);
  };

  var focus = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'focus')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  var barsGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'volume')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + (margin.top + 60 + 20) + ')');

  var context = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'context')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin2.left + ',' + (margin2.top + 60) + ')');

  var legend = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__legend')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', 30)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin2.left + ', 10)');

  legend.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'chart__symbol')
    .text('NASDAQ: AAPL')

  var rangeSelection =  legend
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__range-selection')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(110, 0)');

  d3.csv('./data/aapl.csv', type, function(err, data) {
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x2)
      .on('brush', brushed);

    var xRange = d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

    x.domain(xRange);
    y.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
    y3.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    var min = d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));
    var max = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));

    var range = legend.append('text')
      .text(legendFormat(new Date(xRange[0])) + ' - ' + legendFormat(new Date(xRange[1])))
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)');

    focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y chart__grid')
        .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(''));

    var averageChart = focus.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('class', 'chart__line chart__average--focus line')
        .attr('d', avgLine);

    var priceChart = focus.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('class', 'chart__line chart__price--focus line')
        .attr('d', priceLine);

    focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0 ,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(12, 0)')
        .call(yAxis);

    var focusGraph = barsGroup.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
      .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'chart__bars')
        .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return 155 - y3(d.price); })
        .attr('width', 1)
        .attr('height', function(d) { return y3(d.price); });

    var helper = focus.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'chart__helper')
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)');

    var helperText = helper.append('text')

    var priceTooltip = focus.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'chart__tooltip--price')
      .append('circle')
      .style('display', 'none')
      .attr('r', 2.5);

    var averageTooltip = focus.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'chart__tooltip--average')
      .append('circle')
      .style('display', 'none')
      .attr('r', 2.5);

    var mouseArea = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'chart__mouse')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'chart__overlay')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        helper.style('display', null);
        priceTooltip.style('display', null);
        averageTooltip.style('display', null);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        helper.style('display', 'none');
        priceTooltip.style('display', 'none');
        averageTooltip.style('display', 'none');
      })
      .on('mousemove', mousemove);

    context.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('class', 'chart__area area')
        .attr('d', area2);

    context.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis chart__axis--context')
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height2 - 22) + ')')
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x brush')
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll('rect')
        .attr('y', -6)
        .attr('height', height2 + 7);

    function mousemove() {
      var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
      var i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
      var d0 = data[i - 1];
      var d1 = data[i];
      var d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
      helperText.text(legendFormat(new Date(d.date)) + ' - Price: ' + d.price + ' Avg: ' + d.average);
      priceTooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(d.date) + ',' + y(d.price) + ')');
      averageTooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(d.date) + ',' + y(d.average) + ')');
    }

    function brushed() {
      var ext = brush.extent();
      if (!brush.empty()) {
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
        y.domain([
          d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return (d.date >= ext[0] && d.date <= ext[1]) ? d.price : max; })),
          d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return (d.date >= ext[0] && d.date <= ext[1]) ? d.price : min; }))
        ]);
        range.text(legendFormat(new Date(ext[0])) + ' - ' + legendFormat(new Date(ext[1])))
        focusGraph.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.date); });

        var days = Math.ceil((ext[1] - ext[0]) / (24 * 3600 * 1000))
        focusGraph.attr('width', (40 > days) ? (40 - days) * 5 / 6 : 5)
      }

      priceChart.attr('d', priceLine);
      averageChart.attr('d', avgLine);
      focus.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
      focus.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
    }

    var dateRange = ['1w', '1m', '3m', '6m', '1y', '5y']
    for (var i = 0, l = dateRange.length; i < l; i ++) {
      var v = dateRange[i];
      rangeSelection
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'chart__range-selection')
        .text(v)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (18 * i) + ', 0)')
        .on('click', function(d) { focusOnRange(this.textContent); });
    }

    function focusOnRange(range) {
      var today = new Date(data[data.length - 1].date)
      var ext = new Date(data[data.length - 1].date)

      if (range === '1m')
        ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 1)

      if (range === '1w')
        ext.setDate(ext.getDate() - 7)

      if (range === '3m')
        ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 3)

      if (range === '6m')
        ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 6)

      if (range === '1y')
        ext.setFullYear(ext.getFullYear() - 1)

      if (range === '5y')
        ext.setFullYear(ext.getFullYear() - 5)

      brush.extent([ext, today])
      brushed()
      context.select('g.x.brush').call(brush.extent([ext, today]))
    }

  })// end Data

  function type(d) {
    return {
      date    : parseDate(d.Date),
      price   : +d.Close,
      average : +d.Average,
      volume : +d.Volume,
    }
  }
}());
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code in Stack Snippets.

The contents of `style.css` is in the CSS pane. The JavaScript is in the JavaScript pane. There's nothing in HTML since that's where the JavaScript goes.

```js
 /* global d3, _ */

 (function() {
   var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 50},
  margin2  = {top: 210, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50},
  width    = 764 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height   = 283 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  height2  = 283 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

   var parseDate = d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y').parse,
  bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
  legendFormat = d3.time.format('%b %d, %Y');

   var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
  x2  = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
  y   = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
  y1  = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
  y2  = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]),
  y3  = d3.scale.linear().range([60, 0]);

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
  xAxis2  = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient('bottom'),
  yAxis   = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');

   var priceLine = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate('monotone')
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

   var avgLine = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate('monotone')
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.average); });

   var area2 = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate('monotone')
  .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
  .y0(height2)
  .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

   var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 60);

   svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip')
   .append('rect')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

   var make_y_axis = function () {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(3);
   };

   var focus = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'focus')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

   var barsGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'volume')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + (margin.top + 60 + 20) + ')');

   var context = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'context')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin2.left + ',' + (margin2.top + 60) + ')');

   var legend = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'chart__legend')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 30)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin2.left + ', 10)');

   legend.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'chart__symbol')
  .text('NASDAQ: AAPL')

   var rangeSelection =  legend
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'chart__range-selection')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(110, 0)');

   d3.csv('./data/aapl.csv', type, function(err, data) {
  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on('brush', brushed);

  var xRange = d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

  x.domain(xRange);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
  y3.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  var min = d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));
  var max = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));

  var range = legend.append('text')
    .text(legendFormat(new Date(xRange[0])) + ' - ' + legendFormat(new Date(xRange[1])))
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)');

  focus.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'y chart__grid')
   .call(make_y_axis()
   .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
   .tickFormat(''));

  var averageChart = focus.append('path')
   .datum(data)
   .attr('class', 'chart__line chart__average--focus line')
   .attr('d', avgLine);

  var priceChart = focus.append('path')
   .datum(data)
   .attr('class', 'chart__line chart__price--focus line')
   .attr('d', priceLine);

  focus.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0 ,' + height + ')')
   .call(xAxis);

  focus.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'y axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(12, 0)')
   .call(yAxis);

  var focusGraph = barsGroup.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'chart__bars')
   .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.date); })
   .attr('y', function(d) { return 155 - y3(d.price); })
   .attr('width', 1)
   .attr('height', function(d) { return y3(d.price); });

  var helper = focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__helper')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)');

  var helperText = helper.append('text')

  var priceTooltip = focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__tooltip--price')
    .append('circle')
    .style('display', 'none')
    .attr('r', 2.5);

  var averageTooltip = focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__tooltip--average')
    .append('circle')
    .style('display', 'none')
    .attr('r', 2.5);

  var mouseArea = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart__mouse')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'chart__overlay')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
   helper.style('display', null);
   priceTooltip.style('display', null);
   averageTooltip.style('display', null);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
   helper.style('display', 'none');
   priceTooltip.style('display', 'none');
   averageTooltip.style('display', 'none');
    })
    .on('mousemove', mousemove);

  context.append('path')
   .datum(data)
   .attr('class', 'chart__area area')
   .attr('d', area2);

  context.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x axis chart__axis--context')
   .attr('y', 0)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height2 - 22) + ')')
   .call(xAxis2);

  context.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x brush')
   .call(brush)
    .selectAll('rect')
   .attr('y', -6)
   .attr('height', height2 + 7);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
    var i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
    var d0 = data[i - 1];
    var d1 = data[i];
    var d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    helperText.text(legendFormat(new Date(d.date)) + ' - Price: ' + d.price + ' Avg: ' + d.average);
    priceTooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(d.date) + ',' + y(d.price) + ')');
    averageTooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(d.date) + ',' + y(d.average) + ')');
  }

  function brushed() {
    var ext = brush.extent();
    if (!brush.empty()) {
   x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
   y.domain([
     d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return (d.date >= ext[0] && d.date <= ext[1]) ? d.price : max; })),
     d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return (d.date >= ext[0] && d.date <= ext[1]) ? d.price : min; }))
   ]);
   range.text(legendFormat(new Date(ext[0])) + ' - ' + legendFormat(new Date(ext[1])))
   focusGraph.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.date); });

   var days = Math.ceil((ext[1] - ext[0]) / (24 * 3600 * 1000))
   focusGraph.attr('width', (40 > days) ? (40 - days) * 5 / 6 : 5)
    }

    priceChart.attr('d', priceLine);
    averageChart.attr('d', avgLine);
    focus.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
    focus.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
  }

  var dateRange = ['1w', '1m', '3m', '6m', '1y', '5y']
  for (var i = 0, l = dateRange.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var v = dateRange[i];
    rangeSelection
   .append('text')
   .attr('class', 'chart__range-selection')
   .text(v)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (18 * i) + ', 0)')
   .on('click', function(d) { focusOnRange(this.textContent); });
  }

  function focusOnRange(range) {
    var today = new Date(data[data.length - 1].date)
    var ext = new Date(data[data.length - 1].date)

    if (range === '1m')
   ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 1)

    if (range === '1w')
   ext.setDate(ext.getDate() - 7)

    if (range === '3m')
   ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 3)

    if (range === '6m')
   ext.setMonth(ext.getMonth() - 6)

    if (range === '1y')
   ext.setFullYear(ext.getFullYear() - 1)

    if (range === '5y')
   ext.setFullYear(ext.getFullYear() - 5)

    brush.extent([ext, today])
    brushed()
    context.select('g.x.brush').call(brush.extent([ext, today]))
  }

   })// end Data

   function type(d) {
  return {
    date    : parseDate(d.Date),
    price   : +d.Close,
    average : +d.Average,
    volume : +d.Volume,
  }
   }
 }());
```

```css
.chart__grid {
  stroke: #e7eef4;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.area {
  fill: rgba(255,100,100,0.5);
  clip-path: url("#clip");
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e7eef4;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
/*New*/
.chart text {
  fill: #7f8faf;
}
.chart__line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.2px;
  clip-path: url("#clip");
}
.chart__price--focus {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #2980b9;
}
.chart__average--focus {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #f00;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.chart__overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.chart__tooltip--price {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #f00;
}
.chart__tooltip--average {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #f00;
}
.chart__bars {
  fill: #99c5df;
  opacity: 1;
}
.chart__range-selection text {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  fill: #2980b9;
}
.chart__axis--context text {
  fill: #7f8faf;
}
.chart__axis--context .tick:nth-child(odd) {
  display: none;
}
.chart__axis--context path,
.chart__axis--context line {
  display: none;
}
.chart__area {
  fill: #e6f6fe;
  stroke: #3587bc;
}
.extent {
  fill: #e2f0ff;
  fill: #3587bc;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
.y.axis .tick text {
  text-anchor: start !important;
  fill: #7f8faf;
}
.y.axis .tick line {
  display: none;
}
.y.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: What's your question going to be? Because that seems like a lot of code. Generally we encourage a [mcve], not a whole program.

Comment: It's probably the relative URL you're using here: *d3.csv('./data/aapl.csv', type, function(err, data)*. That CSV file doesn't exist and the console is saying *data is undefined*.

Comment: @BSMP, you're absolutely right. Thanks so much.

Comment: Would you know if I can include the contents of the csv file in Stack Snippets?

Comment: You could make the URL absolute but you might run into the mixed content issue Alon points out in their answer. Even if you don't, it's still making the question reliant on a third party URL. It would be better (assuming this is possible) is to populate the chart with a small set of data that's defined in the JS itself rather than pull from a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Since SO is run over https, you get error loading this script:

```
<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

> Mixed Content: The page at '[Can't seem to run code in Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350021/cant-seem-to-run-code-in-stack-snippets)' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Once you change it to:

```
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You'll get another error, this time related to the code itself:

```
d3.csv('./data/aapl.csv', type, function(err, data) {
```

Because you can't use relative URL path, you need the absolute path to that `csv` file.

On a side note - That's a lot of code! Try reducing it, and provide clear explanation about it. This is definitely not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you might get your question downvoted and closed.